# I don't understand how -12 is the numerator in this difference quotient.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the difference quotient of $$\frac{\left(\frac{1}{12(x+h)+3}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{12x+3}\right)}{h}$$

When I solve it I end up canceling h's at the end and only having -12 as the answer. However, the correct answer is -12 over the denominator of the fractions in the numerator.

I solved it like this:

$$\frac{\left(\frac{1}{12x+12h+3}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{12x+3}\right)}{h}$$

Then multiplied each fraction by $(12x+12h+3)(12x+3)$ to get:

$$\frac{12x+3-12x-12h-3}{h}$$

Then simplify the numerator to this:

$$\frac{-12h}{h}$$

Then cancel h which gave me -12.

Comment: As a suggestion:  if you believe the answer is $-12$ regardless of the value of $x$ then it must be $-12$ when $x=0$.  Is it?

Comment: When you subtract fractions, you first find a common denominator:  $\frac{q}{r}-\frac{s}{t} = \frac{qt-rs}{rt}.$

Comment: If you multiply the numerator by some term you must also multiply the denominator by that term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\frac{\frac{1}{12(x+h)+3}-\frac{1}{12x+3}}{h}=\frac{1}{h}\cdot \left(\frac{1}{12(x+h)+3}-\frac{1}{12x+3}\right)=\\
\frac{1}{h}\cdot \frac{12x+3-12(x+h)-3}{(12(x+h)+3)(12x+3)}=\\
\frac{1}{h}\cdot \frac{-12h}{(12(x+h)+3)(12x+3)}=\frac{-12}{(12(x+h)+3)(12x+3)}
$$

Comment: OOOO! I see, so what was confusing me was I thought I needed to distribute h but it just cancels the top and I forgot to multiply the top and bottom by (12(x+h)+3)(12x+3)). Perfect thank you!